# How to put the "yes" program into the background?

Tags: background-process

When I activate the `yes` program, it does not react to the `CTRL+Z` pause (nor to `CTRL+C` to stop it).

I know no other ways to run a program in the background than using `CTRL+Z` and then a `bg`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? By "activate" do you just mean run? Are you piping the output of yes somewhere? Or redirecting it? The "yes" program will definitely respond to ^C or ^Z but it's possible that the flood of output it's generating means it'll take a while for the interrupt/pause to take effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ampersand at the end of a command will cause the command to be run in the background right from the start:

```
yes &
```

`yes` should respond to `CTRL+C` and definitely `CTRL+Z`, though. Maybe it's just taking a while for it to take effect for some reason.

Comment: The only result I get when, eg. `CTRL+C`ing while the `yes` is on, is getting `^C` briefly printed, and then `y` ad infinitum.

`yes &` only makes the command start with a half-second delay.

Long waiting, and still no sign of `yes` hiding in the background or ending.

Comment: You are conflating running in the background with not generating output.  Hint: `tostop`

Comment: @dziadek1990 `yes &` (running `yes` in the background) won't make it end or not output to the current terminal ad infinitum. That's the expected behavior. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @PSkocik Okay, thanks, :) I understand now what `yes &` is supposed to do. But still `yes` does not react to my `CTRL+C` -- now what I want to achieve is to be able to turn off the `yes` program with that key combination, which for some reason does not work. How can I find out the reasons for those keys not working?

Comment: Give me ssh access to your PC and I'll test it out for ya. No, seriously, it's hard to tell. What kind of terminal and system are you at?

Comment: `Fedora-Live-Workstation-x86_64-21-5` (on a VBox VM, if it makes a difference), terminal: `xterm-256color` -------------- [there will be a possible 24+h delay to your request; other priorities for now]

Comment: @PSkocik Problem solved; apparently I accidentally deleted some system files previously, which caused this and other problems. Thanks for the offered help anyways. :)